# Plone/SQLAlchemy(?) - How can I import a python package (i.e. sqlalchemy) in a module in a subpackage?

Tags: sqlalchemy, plone

I am trying to import sqlalchemy in a module in a subpackage.

Here is my folder layout

```
PloneInstance
    my.package
        my
            package
                subpackage
```

In the buildout.cfg file of the root folder, I add "sqlalchemy" to the eggs.

In my.package, in configure.zcml, I add:

In the subpackage, I have a blank __init__.py file, a configure.zcml file, and a file called mymodule.py

In mymodule.py I have a line for importing sqlalchemy

```
import sqlalchemy
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error when I try to run an instance:

```
ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy
```

I'm assuming I am missing a step.  How do I properly import python packages?

Thank you in advance.  I apologize if my terminology is off.

Edit:
The module in question I am importing from turned out to be zope.sqlalchemy.
I accidentally overlooked this because prior to moving files to a subpackage, the import statement for zope.sqlalchemy was working without adding zope.sqlalchemy to the eggs section of the buildout.

Comment: Did you rerun buildout after adding a new egg to the buildout.cfg?

Comment: Yes.  Anytime I add to the buildout.cfg, I make sure to rerun buildout.  I did so once more in case, but unfortunately it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I found the error I was having.  In the same file where I import sqlalchemy, I also import some things from zope.sqlalchemy, and it couldn't find zope's sqlalchemy module.  Earlier, my folder structure was different in which I did not use a subpackage at all.  Importing from zope.sqlalchemy was working at that point in time, so I accidentally overlooked needing to add zope.sqlalchemy to the buildout file.  I'm assuming that I'll come across similar problems, but atleast I know how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the setup.py file at the top directory of your package. You'll find a section like:

```
      install_requires=['setuptools',
         # -*- Extra requirements: -*-
      ],
```

In place of the "Extra requirements' comment, put a comma-separated list of strings specifying your package's requirements. You may even specify versions.

Do not add standard Plone packages to the list. They're taken for granted.

Re-run buildout after specifying your requirements. The result is that the new install requires will be added to your Python environment when you start Plone.